# Python 3.4 - Opening a file in a module with a different directory

Tags: file, python-3.4

I have a package that looks like the following

```
package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

In `module.py` I have something like this

```
def function(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        # do stuff
```

Somewhere else in an arbitrary directory I have a python file that looks something like this

```
import package

package.function("some_file.txt")
```

But upon running it, it's giving me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "some_file.txt"`.

The problem is that the absolute path of `some_file.txt` may look something like `C:\Users\USER\Documents\some_file.txt`, but in `package.function` the path absolute path is something like `C:\Users\USER\Documents\package\some_file.txt`. Is there any way I can make it so that calling `package.function` from some file outside the `package` directory automatically includes the absolute path of the file I want to open?

Sorry if my terminology is really ambiguous, I'm really unfamiliar with `os` stuff.

**Edit:** The exact file setup I have looks like this:

```
directory/
    foo.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        module.py
    another_directory/
        bar.txt
```

And `foo.py` looks exactly like this

```
import package

package.function("another_directory/bar.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the point.

It's not important where the source code lies, relative paths (and pure file names *are* relative paths) are always interpreted relative to the directory that the program process runs in (ie. the directory you are when you type `python C:\Path\to\my\python\code\code.py` )

Comment: I'm not getting it. What about something like `pygame.image.load(file_name)`? `file_name` can just be something like `img.png` and yet even though `pygame.image.load` is in some other directory, it works fine.

Comment: Yes, because no matter where your source code is, if img.png is in the same folder you where when you started python, it will be found.

Comment: Then how come when I run my example file that imports `package` and calls `package.function`, its giving me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "some_file.txt"`?

Comment: I don't know -- you're not telling us anything about your file system structure. Nevertheless, `open(..)` will *always* be relative to the current working directory (`os.curdir`, btw), because it just calls the underlying operating system call.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question to include the exact details of the file structure.

Comment: Actually, don't worry about it. I, uh, I just forget a letter in the file name, everything's fine now, LOL! Thanks for helping me out, and sorry for wasting your time!